# how to copy from one google sheet to another with button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have made this in excel but cannot use it online. so i made it in google sheets but it does not work. What i want to do:
data ( values only, no formats) from sheet Tmrw range C3:Y20 copy to sheet Today range C3:y20, and after that clear data from sheet Tmrw range C3:Y20
i used this code:

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("Tmrw"!C3:Y20");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
var destRange = destSheet.getRange("Today!C3:Y20");
source.copyTo (destRange,"Today!C3:Y20);
source.clear ();
}
```

it does not work. i am not surprised.

the file is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11uyaRe7khP9PywXKkEh5e5xWLvm68Nw58R6dHkaTxvk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When `getRange` of Class Spreadsheet, you can include the sheet name to the A1Notation.

  - In this case, `ss.getRange("'Today'!C3:Y20")` can be used instead of `ss.getSheetByName("Today");`.
- `"Tmrw"!C3:Y20"` and `"Today!C3:Y20` are not enclosed by `"`. In this case, please modify to `"Tmrw!C3:Y20"` and `"'Tmrw'!C3:Y20"`, and `"Today!C3:Y20"` and `"'Today'!C3:Y20"`.
- In your situation, I thought that the arguments of `copyTo` of Class Range is `copyTo(destination)`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange("'Tmrw'!C3:Y20");
  var destRange = ss.getRange("'Today'!C3:Y20");
  source.copyTo(destRange);
  source.clear();
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use `getSheetByName`, you can also modify your script as follows.

  ```
    function moveValuesOnly() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tmrw");
      var source = srcSheet.getRange("C3:Y20");
      var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
      var destRange = dstSheet.getRange("C3:Y20");
      source.copyTo(destRange);
      source.clear();
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)
- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String))
- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Comment: thanks, i am very new at this. thank you so much.

Comment: @Dina Kütt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.